# How to extract the first element of a 2d array in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, hsv

Let's say I have a 3d array in python that looks like this [[[3, 4, 9], [5, 3, 1], [6, 4, 2]], [[2, 3, 6], [7, 9, 10], [5, 12, 4]], [[7, 5, 1], [3, 1, 2], [6, 5, 2]]]. I want to extract the first element of each entry and put them all into a 1d array like this [3, 5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 7, 3, 6]. I'm working with an hsv image where each pixel has a 3 tuple where each entry corresponds to the hue, saturation, and value. I want to extract just the hue value of each pixel and put it into a 1d array. Here's what my code looks like.

```
import numpy as np
import colorsys
from skimage import color
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg", 1)
img_hsv = color.rgb2hsv(img)
b = []
for i in img_hsv:
    b.append(i[0][0])
```

The problem is that the image I'm reading in is 640x480 and the shape of b is just 640 which makes me think I haven't got all the pixels in the image. So my two questions are, is my for loop correct and do I even need a for loop to do this or does python have a library that can do this?

Comment: What's wrong with img_hsv[:, 0]?

Comment: Would that produce the desired results? I'm new to python so I have no idea how these things work.

Comment: Assuming img_hsv is a 2d array, yes.  Here is what's going on, by calling img_hsv[:, 0] you are slicing out all values (":") in the first column ("0"), yielding a 1d array with values of [3, 2, 7].  Alternatively, if you called img_hsv[0, :] (i.e. all values in the first ROW) you would get a 1d array with values of [3, 5, 6].

Comment: img_hsv is a type of 2d array. Basically something like img_hsv[10][12] would produce a line like [153, 25, 142] which represents the hue, saturation, and value. I just want that first value for each pixel and put into a 1d array.

Comment: Are you sure the array is 2d and not 3d?  What does img.shape return?

Comment: It returns (640, 480, 3)

Comment: Right, that's 3d.  Again, slicing is the way to go: img_hsv[:, :, 0] (now for 3d array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing the array is by far the fastest method available.  The array you are importing is 3-dimensional in nature, just as an example let's create a 3d array from random numbers from the domain 0-10:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3, 3))

img.shape
Out[36]:
(5, 3, 3)

Out[37]: 
array([[[8, 0, 8],
    [9, 0, 5],
    [9, 0, 4]],

   [[5, 2, 5],
    [3, 3, 1],
    [3, 4, 0]],

   [[1, 2, 2],
    [9, 0, 6],
    [2, 5, 9]],

   [[8, 6, 2],
    [4, 5, 1],
    [3, 3, 6]],

   [[8, 0, 7],
    [0, 6, 0],
    [5, 2, 3]]])
```

Now, you want to select the first value (in your case, the hue) via:

```
hue = img[:, :, 0]

hue
Out[43]: 
array([[8, 9, 9],
       [5, 3, 3],
       [1, 9, 2],
       [8, 4, 3],
       [8, 0, 5]])
```

This will yield a 2d array, but you want a 1d: just flatten it

```
hue = hue.flatten()

hue
Out[44]: array([8, 9, 9, 5, 3, 3, 1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 3, 8, 0, 5])
```

Voila, a 1d array.  Read how flatten works to understand how it sorts the output.

While slicing is the fastest option here, you ask how your for loop can be improved.  The problem with your loop is you are only going over the rows.  Since you are operating over the first two dimension of your 3d array you need to have two for loops (warning, this is very slow...some reading on "Big O notation" may be helful).  The following changes to your loop will suffice

```
b = []
for row in img_hsv.shape[0]:
    for col in img_hsv.shape[1]:
        b.append(hsv[row, col, 0])
```

One more thing, you said you wanted your output (b) to be an array.  You currently have it defined as a list, you can convert it to an arry via

```
b = np.array(b)
```

#### EDIT

Just for fun, and to drive home the point of how slow looping is, I timed each option.

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 100, (640, 480, 3))
iterations = 100

d1 = dt.datetime.now()
for i in range(iterations):
    hue = img[:, :, 0]
print('Slicing total time: ', dt.datetime.now() - d1)



d1 = dt.datetime.now()
for i in range(iterations):
    hue = []
    for row in range(img.shape[0]):
        for col in range(img.shape[1]):
            hue.append(img[row, col, 0])

print('Multiple total looping time: ', dt.datetime.now() - d1)

Slicing total time:  0:00:00.002107
Multiple total looping time:  0:00:08.860522
```

Or 20 microseconds per file vs 80 ms per file (factor of 4200 times faster).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:
two_D = [[3, 5, 6], [2, 7, 5], [7, 3, 6]]
I usually call these arrays as a list of lists too.
If you print two_D[0] you can see that it will print out your first list.
If you want to reach the first element of your first list:
two_D[0][0].

For filling a 1d array in your question:

```
one_d = []
for i in range(len(two_D)):
    one_d.append(two_D[i][0])
```

I haven't work with pixels and images and can't help with your other question, sorry!

Comment: This will work for small arrays, but will be incredibly slow.  It is better to do slicing instead of looping through the array.  Depending on array size, slicing can be one or two (maybe three!) orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the list of lists, use `next` to obtain the first items as a tuple, and use the `list` constructor to convert the tuple to a list (the list conversion is optional if you don't need the result as a list):

```
list(next(zip(*img_hsv)))
```

**EDIT:** Your revised question now has a list of lists of lists (a 3d array as you say), so you can flatten the list first with a generator expression and apply the same logic above:

```
list(next(zip(*(t for s in img_hsv for t in s))))
```

Comment: I don't think this works as the OP wanted.  This solution will pull the first row from each sub-array, while the OP wanted the first level of the third dimension.

Comment: Please check the OP's edit history and timestamps. The OP changed the question after I gave the answer. It was a 2D array before the change. The first answer, given by Sina Safarabadi, is also based on the OP's original question as you can see.

Comment: You are correct.  FWIW, I appreciate like your solution (though slicing is still faster) and I did not down vote you.  If I had, I would change it to an up vote.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
from array import *
a = [[[3, 4, 9], [5, 3, 1], [6, 4, 2]], [[2, 3, 6], [7, 9, 10], [5, 12, 4]], [[7, 5, 1], [3, 1, 2], [6, 5, 2]]]
b=[]
j=0
m=0
print(a[0][0])
while j<len(a):
    print("J:",j)
    l=0
    for k in a[j]:
         print(j,l)
         b.insert(m, a[j][l][0])
         l+=1
         m+=2
    j+=1 
print(b)
```

The j and m variable are used to track the nested iterations within the  array (a), j increments within the first nest while m increments by 2 within the second nest, so that all 0th elements of each nested array can be gotten and inserted into the array (b)

Comment: FYI, while this might work (I have not tested it) it will be extremely slow.  Check my answer for a time comparison.